# Quickly access sorted subset

Tags: algorithm, sorting, numpy

Let's say I have an `n` by `d` matrix `X`, with `n` samples and `d` features. Let's assume that I can presort `X` as much as I realistically want (for example, have a matrix of indices for `X` sorted by each individual feature). The algorithm I am using requires me to do something like this:

```
process X sorted by feature j
after processing, we create a subset of X, X'
process X' sorted by feature j'
...
eventually there are no more subsets to process
```

Is there a way to do this without having to resort `X` by the feature I need?

Here's pseudocode for what I've been able to come up with so far:

```
I = np.array([np.argsort(X[:, j]) for j in range(d)])
process X sorted by feature j = process X[I[j]]
now we get a subset of indices S
but how do we process X[S] sorted by j'?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also keep the original row index in each row. This way, you would just need to filter the array sorted by `j'` by the index. That is, you subset of indices `S` corresponds to a subset of rows in the original array. You can filter the array sorted by `j'` on the index (taking only those rows whose index is in the subset of original row indices that are in `S`). This way, you obtain a subset of the array sorted by `j'` that contains only those rows that were in `S`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm having a little trouble understanding it. Could you be more specific?

Comment: Ok, this seems pretty good. In order for this to be fast, though, S would have to be a hash set, and I don't think numpy has an implementation for that. Do you think I should just use a python set for S?

Comment: @michaelsnowden Yes, that would be the first thing I'd try.